# Searching within a distance in SQL

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I have database with a list of contacts with puesdo coordinates of where they live. Here's a sample:

```
name    e_point  n_point
David   102      345
James   174      746
Ali     460      584
Kevin   364      479
Mark    385      274
```

I was wondering is it possible to create a query that can search within a distance of the two coordinates? E.g., I want a list of people who live within a 20 sqr mile radius of James.

What functions can help me do this?

Comment: I think it's possible but only if i knew what "puesdo coordinates" means.  I googled this term but couldn't find anything that explained what it means

Comment: @Tin Tran : Those puesdo coordinates is basically the easting and northing coordinates. I just wanted to use something with short figures as a test, before moving to the real thing.

Comment: so like e_point would be like -x and n_point would be like -y?

Comment: @Tin Tran : yes, but without the negatives. If I'm right easting and northing have no negatives.

Comment: If it's possible to switch, [Postgres has geometry built in](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html).

Comment: @Schwern : I can't, the database is on MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql syntax:

```
SELECT name FROM `table` WHERE SQRT(
POW(e_point - (SELECT e_point FROM `table` WHERE name='james'), 2) + 
POW(n_point - (SELECT n_point FROM `table` WHERE name='james'), 2)) < 20
AND name <> 'james'
```

Notice:

1. you need to change 'name' in 3 places.
2. subqueries added for let you run one query with just one variable (name). If you remove subqueries, you need to run 2 queries (first query retrieving coord, and second query searching near people)
3. equation is:

[image]

Where p1=(p1x, p1y) and p2=(p2x, p2y)

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the code and the formula used.

Comment: @Gerardo : Thank you for the suggestion. I was wondering canyou explain the `POW` and `SQRT` function? Also, why is the reason behind the subquery. I'm just asking because I want to learn about the rationale behind the code.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the distance between 2 coordinates you need to get the [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), as the earth is rounded and measurement of distance is affected by this fact.

[image]

Doing this with SQL would be something like this according to the [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#populating-the-table):

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Great circle distance is probably overkill for 20 miles. What's the difference if you assume it's on a plane?

Comment: @Danny H : thanks a lot for suggestion and code. I'm assuming this is for latitude and longitude? Can it be used for other cordinates too?

Answer (score 1):

if your coordinates represent like x and y coordinates you can use something like this (just replaces occurrences of `contacts` with your actual table name) distance returned is the distance from 'James':

```
SELECT T2.name,
       SQRT(POWER(T2.e_point-T1.e_point,2)+
            POWER(T2.n_point-T1.n_point,2)) as distance
FROM contacts T1
INNER JOIN contacts T2 ON
  SQRT(POWER(T2.e_point-T1.e_point,2)+
       POWER(T2.n_point-T1.n_point,2)) <= 20
WHERE T1.name = 'James'
AND T1.name != T2.name
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3990/1)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! BTW, can you give explanation of why you used the `SQRT` and `POWER` functions? Just want to understand the code a bit better.

Comment: SQRT gives you square root of a number like sqrt(9) is 3...POWER() gives you the exponent of a number like POWER(3,2) is 3 to the 2nd power so like 3 squared is 9.... and the whole formula is based on just the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Ah, I see. That for the explanation. I looked at the pythagorean theorem formula and it makes sense.

Comment: Two questions: 1) why did you join the same table onto each other? 2) why do you need to POWER the number?

Comment: T1 grabs James' location, T2 is grabs other people's locations,  I needed to Power the number because that's how pythagorean theorem is defined ... a squared + b squared = c squared. so c is the sqrt of (a squared + b squared)...POWER(number,2) is just number squared

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.